# How to make Entry box in Tkinter transparent?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to make my Entry box without any color and only shows the cursor so it will blend with the canvas image. Here is what I want to make [objective design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h6Ds.png) and here is what I am able to make [current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePphv.png).

I did try the `root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "yellow")` but it will also make the frame invisible. How do I make the entry box transparent without affecting the background. My code is based on the link below.

> https://github.com/ajinkyapadwad/Tkinter-HosoKeys

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853195/how-to-make-window-transparent-but-widgets-like-frame-or-label-visible-in-tkinte/63855362)

Comment: the basically the trick is make another frame on top of it?

Comment: Im not sure, try implementing it?

Comment: this is pretty much what I did, the frame becomes transparent too

Comment: Im not sure of the effect thats mention, but generally its not possible to make window transparent while the widgets are not. With the code you mentioned

Comment: I don't know how it works on `Windows` and `MacOS` but on Linux you can't create widget with transparent background. If you use `Canvas` then you can use `Canvas.create_text()` to put text without background - but it would need to write all code to get pressed key and update text on canvas.